# Java regex for specific case

Tags: java, regex

I am trying to reformat a string to my desired format. I have been trying to figure this out for a while but I can't think of any elegant solution using regexs. I have come up with a  solution using String's `indexOf()` and `replace()` but it's not exactly pretty.

I want to convert any string so that there is exactly one space on each side of the "-".

Possible inputs:

```
"abc- abc"
"abc -abc"
"abc - abc"
"abc-abc"
```

and each case should be converted to

```
"abc - abc"
```

Thanks for any help. Let me know if you need more clarification.

Comment: Even if your initial solution wasn't pretty, you should still show it as part of the question. It demonstrates that you at least tried something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [`String#replaceAll`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29):

```
String pattern = "\\s*-\\s*";
String s1 = "abc- abc";
String s2 = "abc -abc";
String s3 = "abc - abc";
String s4 = "abc-abc";
System.out.println(s1.replaceAll(pattern, " - "));
System.out.println(s2.replaceAll(pattern, " - "));
System.out.println(s3.replaceAll(pattern, " - "));
System.out.println(s4.replaceAll(pattern, " - "));
```

Explanation of `"\\s*-\\s*"` regex:

- `\\s` => space (in fact, is `\s` but Java needs double `\\`)
- `*`   => 0 or more
- `-`   => simple '-'

More info about Regular Expressions: [Regular Expression Basic Syntax Reference](http://www.regular-expressions.info/reference.html)

Comment: doh, I'm an idiot. I was using \\S instead of \\s which is why mine wasn't working.

Answer (score 2):

Using `\s*-\s*` pattern:

```
"abc- abc".replaceAll("\\s*-\\s*", " - "))
```

Answer (score 1):

The simplest would probably be to use this pattern:

```
[ ]?-[ ]?
```

Like this:

```
str = str.replaceAll("[ ]?-[ ]?", " - ");
```